# Anyone know of something like Fluid, for Windows?

Tags: windows, mac, browser

I'm looking for something like [Fluid](http://fluidapp.com/) (Mac OS X), for Windows. It's an app that lets you run a single browser window, as a standalone app. So I can have a Fluid 'app' each for say Fogbugz and Stack Overflow, and my normal browser activities don't interfere with them (shutdowns, crashes etc). To most intents and purposes they appear to be self-contained applications in their own right.

I run Fluid myself on my Mac and I'm looking for something similar for my partner to run on her Windows XP machine.

I'm half-tempted to drum something up myself in Delphi but I'd want it to use whatever the user's default browser is (eg Firefox, Chrome) and I'm not sure the amount of pain in trying to do that is worth my time - I'm not short of things to do! Much happier if I can just find something off-the-shelf to do it. :-)

Comment: The problem with Prism and Google Application shortcuts is that they share cookie state across instances. Prism does not do this. Any one else have any other suggestions?

Comment: I have tried Web2Desk by https://desktop.appmaker.xyz/ and it works great for all 3 platforms(Mac, Linux, Windows)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

What you are after is [Prism](https://mozillalabs.com/prism/), which is based on Firefox. It allows you to "split web applications out of their browser and run them directly on their desktop." It is available for Windows, Mac and Linux

Comment: Good call, going to try that out ;-)

Comment: This image persuaded me: http://people.mozilla.com/~faaborg/files/prism/announcement/startmenu550.png

Comment: Prism has done the job nicely. I've also installed it on my Mac, as there are a few differences between it and Fluid that I want to explore. Thanks for the link!

Comment: "As of November 2010, Prism is listed as an _inactive_ project at the Mozilla labs website." http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozilla_Prism

Comment: project inactive/closed

Comment: I have tried Web2Desk by desktop.appmaker.xyz and it works great for all 3 platforms(Mac, Linux, Windows)

Answer (score 27):

Well there is Google Chrome. It has [Application Shortcuts](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2008/09/try-gmail-in-google-chrome.html).

That creates a shortcut so you can see the webpage as it is a normal app, with it's own frame.

Is that what you're looking for?

**EDIT**

I found this [nice picture](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2008/09/try-gmail-in-google-chrome.html)

[image]

Comment: I created a shortcut for gmail and my app launcher recognize it immediately

Answer (score 1):

I had considerable difficulty getting Prism to work with a proxy.  I ended up creating my Prism app (with icon on desktop), then editing the webapp.ini file for the Prism app (located in Documents and Settings\User\ApplicationData\WebApps) to have the URL be about:config.

Then fire up your prism app (in this case it was for Google Tasks), and edit the network.proxy settings accordingly for your network.

Close out of the prism app, and return the webapp.ini file to its previous state (url= the desired website instead of about:config).

Proxy should work now!

Answer (score 0):

Prism is considered an "Inactive Project" by Mozilla.

This is the link for Chrome Application Shortcuts, which work only on Windows and Linux: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95710?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

I use AutoHotKey to trigger some sites. I hit Win + k and my calendar opens.

```
#k::run "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --app=https://www.google.com/calendar/render?pli=1
```